# bootstrap 3 tooltip title function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

This is a dumb question I'm sure, but how can I pass a function to the tooltip for the title?

```
<span id="spanCount" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" class="badge tip" data-original-title="getNames()">26</span>
```

The tooltip is just displaying the text "getNames()"

```
function getNames(){
            return 'testing';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try data-title instead of data-original-title

```
<span id="spanCount" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" class="badge tip" data-title="getNames()">26</span>
```

or via JavaScript

```
$('#mytooltip').tooltip({title: function(){return 'testing';} })
```

Comment: Only the JavaScript method you demonstrate works. You can't specify JS functions via `data-*` attributes in Bootstrap (due to the inherent ambiguity), so your first method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
$("[rel='tooltip'], .tooltip").tooltip();

<span class="tooltip" title="Sample tooltip">26</span>
```

You can use any CSS selector inside the jQuery function $() to select any element on the page in any way.